# C#/.NET Garbage intensive system calls

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, system-calls

What are the .net library calls and system calls that cause the most garbage?
I read somewhere DayLightTime causes a lot of garbage and result in garbage collector activity.

I need to find a list of such calls.

Comment: `new List<decimal>(Int32.MaxValue)` probably causes quite a bit of garbage.

Comment: String manipulation, typically.  Garbage is a good thing, free memory getting recycled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean 'which calls allocate the most memory that they then free', then it's completely unanswerable, as the amount of memory they use is very likely to depend on the size of the job you give them.

The .NET framework source is available for download if you want to see how a particular call works.   http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Why?

Strive to make your code as clean (in style, not garbage) as possible. If it is too slow, profile and find the problem. Making a list of methods not to call to try and reduce garbage in the future seems like a losing idea.

Comment: I want to aceive lowest latency possible. I want least dynamic memory allocation which in turn enables least GC overhead and least jitter and performance overhead.